# OutOfMemory Error of Bitmap used in button background

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created an activity which is having multiple Buttons. With in the Button i used images as Background.
While running the app is not working and it is showing an outOfMemory Error of Bitmap. 
How to solve this. please help me.

```
enter code here
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eaeaea"
tools:context="com.example.softtech.btngrid.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item1"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_item2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item2"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_item1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item4"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="257dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_item3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item3"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="257dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_item4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item6"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="498dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_item5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item5"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="498dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_item6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item8"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="739dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_item7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item7"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="739dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_item8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item10"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="980dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_item9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_item9"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="980dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cartoon9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_item10"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I have declared the Buttons in Main activity.

Please Help me with this problem.
I am new to android development.

Comment: Check your images size. try to reduce them.

Comment: I have already used the same images in GridView. and there i have applied bitmap Funcion. there it is working fine.

Comment: use .png images for background

Comment: @ravirs try `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest

Comment: @ravirs if you have android studio 3.0 then convert all images to webp. by right clicking on drawable folder

Comment: ok i will try both .png images and android:largeheap="true"

Comment: yes i am using android 3.0. But i didn't see webp option after right click

Comment: @ravirs then on right click drawable folder and last option will be convert to webp. try that also

Comment: i selected the convert to webp option but it is showing same error.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file use this :-

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

and use `.png` files instead of `.jpg` and try to use low size of images.

Comment: i have implemented  android:largeHeap="true" stilll it is showing the same error... how i can i reduce the size of m images.

Comment: change format of images you can change online using png to jpg converter